# Passport Local Strategy doesn't successfully redirect (302)

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm learning authentication via passportjs, and currently have a signup page that (when successfully authenicates a user) will render a profile page.

My local strategy isn't successfully redirecting, and I can't figure out why. All middleware is required where needed and installed. The page just renders in an infinite loop; but will failureRedirect correctly.

config/passport

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, username, password, done) => {

    User.findOne({username : username}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) {return done(err)}
        if(user){
            return done(null, false)
        }

        let newUser = new User()
        newUser.username = req.body.username
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPasssword(req.body.password)

        newUser.save((err) => {
            if(err) {return done(err)}
            return done(null, newUser)
        })
    })
}))
```

controllers/user

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local', {

    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/index',
    failureFash: true
}))

router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile',{user: req.user})
})
```

views/signup.ejs

```
<form action='/signup' method='post'>
Username: <br>
<input type='text' id='username' name='username'><br>
Password: <br>
<input type='password' id='password' name='password'><br>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

server.js

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)


const app = express()

mongoose.connect(my DaaS information is here)

let routes = require('./controllers/user')

require('./config/passport')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(routes)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cookieParser)

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})

}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: You are returning `false` when you find user (`return done(null, false)`), instead you should return user itself `return done(null, user)`

Comment: With this being the signup page, I'm returning false if the user is found in the database (because that specific username already exists). So that answer goes against the logic of the program; however even then, the page still sits there rendering a 302...